# imacros click on flash element of the page

Tags: javascript, flash, imacros

I want to know how to use imacros to click on element of the page that is in flash

```
http://i.imgur.com/djkiv.jpg
```

Here is the picture of code of that element.

Also can imacros select element of the page and click coordinates on that element?

i need all of this because I need to find a way to make a mouse hovering movement on flash and to click somewhere on flash on that page. Also I tried DS commands in imacros and for some reason they didn't work.